Problem checking internet connectivity in flutter with connectivity_plus package
I'm trying to check if a user is connected to the internet before I redirect them to the homepage. Connectivity result shows as connectivity.wifi when I am connected to the internet and returns true. But when I disconnect from the internet on the emulator, it shows connectivity.none and returns true which still redirect the user to the homepage. I don't want to direct the user to the homepage.
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  Future<bool> checkInternetConnectivity() async {
    try {
      final connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
      print('Connectivity result: $connectivityResult'); 
      return connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error checking connectivity: $e'); 
      return false; // Assuming no connectivity in case of an error
    }
}

This is the redirect code:
void startTimer() {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () async {
      bool isConnected = await checkInternetConnectivity();
      print('isConnected: $isConnected'); // Debug print

      if (isConnected) {
        if (await firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
          firebaseAuth.currentUser != null
              ? AssistanceMethods.readCurrentUserOnlineInfo()
              : null;
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => MainScreen()));
        } else {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => LoginScreen()));
        }
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => ErrorMsgScreen()));
      }
    });
}


As per the documentation here, the connectivityResult is a list and it should be used like this:
final List<ConnectivityResult> connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
final noInternet = connectivityResult.contains(ConnectivityResult.none)

So your checkInternetConnnectivity() method should be:
Future<bool> checkInternetConnectivity() async {
    try {
      final connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
      print('Connectivity result: $connectivityResult'); 
      return !connectivityResul.contains(ConnectivityResult.none);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error checking connectivity: $e'); 
      return false; // Assuming no connectivity in case of an error
    }
  }



Hi Godwin, please vote up and approve the answer if it works for you. Thank you.
